# turn my TCP android application to jar

Tags: java, android

I've built a TCP server and now I would like to turn it into a jar so I can use it in many different app. So basically later on I'd like to just include it in other projects. if it was just a list of functions I could figure it out but it's not I'm so I'm not sure. I thought about making it all just one function but it wouldn't run, when I called the function the app would just fail.

Also I hope other people can find this server code useful for their own projects

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 private ServerSocket serverSocket;
 Handler updateConversationHandler;
 Thread serverThread = null;
 public String serverIP = "127.0.0.1";
 private InetAddress serverAddr;
 public static final int SERVERPORT = 4444;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    updateConversationHandler = new Handler();
    this.serverThread = new Thread(new ServerThread());
    this.serverThread.start();

}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    try {
        serverSocket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

class ServerThread implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        Socket socket = null;
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            try {
                socket = serverSocket.accept();
                CommunicationThread commThread = new CommunicationThread(socket);
                new Thread(commThread).start();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

class CommunicationThread implements Runnable {
    private Socket clientSocket;
    private BufferedReader input;
    public CommunicationThread(Socket clientSocket) {
        this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
        try {
            this.input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.clientSocket.getInputStream()));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            try {
                String read = input.readLine();
                updateConversationHandler.post(new updateUIThread(read));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What's the question here? How to create a JAR file? How to design an API?

Comment: Whats the question is the good question here :D :P

Comment: I thought the questions was obvious. How can this be turned into a usable api?

Comment: There's nothing obvious about it at all. When your title says one thing and the body of your question says something else, it is bound to cause confusion. Your actual question is too broad to answer here.